# Large screen multi touch interactive application design

Tags: c#, java, html, apache-flex, multi-touch

I am supposed to design an application for a large multitouch screen. By large, i mean newscaster large (around 55 inches and above). The application is an interactive map.

My questions is: which technology to develop the application in. My first idea was to make it in Adobe Flex, but then there is HTML5 too... 
There must be some awesome Java library for touch interactions too, but then on Windows platform there must be C# library too?

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

The backend is probably going to be in Java EE.

Is there a specialized touch maps sdk?

Comment: `The best` language is the language you `know`. Can't see a way how can this question become answerable in Q&A fashion. It's pretty broad and certainly opinionated. I'm sorry, but I'm voting to close...

Comment: i need opinions... i need to weigh my options.. please lemme see some answers before closing.... as the answers come in I will try to reformulate the question to make it a better fit to the forums directives1

Comment: If you need opinions and discussion, it would be better to find a forum and ask there. I'm afraid this isn't really a place for this question... http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: as the answers come in I will try to reformulate the question to make it a better fit to the forums directives... with the answers I get from here, i will know which forums to post my question to...

Comment: @Marci-man is this going to be a Windows application? or a Web-application? or a multi-platform? [This is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpoLEGlkDGU)  that made me fall in love with WPF and XAML.

Comment: it is going to be windows... thank you so much for not trying to close the door in my face :)

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel?

[Ventuz](https://www.ventuz.com/) hands down best touch software I have used and I use it daily. It's specifically for large multi-touch presentations.

If you are looking to build it yourself, you will have a long long way to go. Ventuz is extremely flexible and will let you do anything you'll need to do with touch for the most part.

(And they are based in Germany, like you)

Here are some demos they showed last year at NAB

[image: Election Map]
[image: Multi screen]
<sub>(source: [ventuz.com](http://www.ventuz.com/images/news/company/12-04-27%20NAB%202012/nab_2012_11.jpg))</sub>

Comment: the thing is, the application is supposed to be doing a lot of specialized tasks with a map of a particular country... it is suppose to help in analyzing election coverage of a local news channel

Comment: That is fine. Ventuz has done many election coverage of local news channels. In fact, I have build one myself. You can import 3D models and bind each individual model to touch events to do things. It's all non-linear and allows you to integrate it into whatever other application you need as well. There is also scripting engines and logic machines heavily built into the Ventuz software.

Comment: since the website does*t really talk about prices... could you perhaps tell me what sort of price range am i looking at when I go for a 55" display? additionally, is there an SDK

Comment: http://www.ventuz.com/news/2012/207/NAB_recap_%E2%80%93_Got_screens.aspx 
Here is an example of an election map they made for NAB. My company is actually close partners with them and are offical OEMs. The licenses are different for Runtime and Designers. Designer if for creation, Runtime is for playback. If you only need one licenses, a Designer will do both. Designers are $10000 Euro and runtimes are $1000 Euro last I checked. They also have a much cheaper touch designer as well.

Comment: And no, not an SDK to access the renderer directly, but all the tools you'll need are there for the most part, and anything that isn't is possible through scripts and other methods. There is a little bit of a learning curve, but believe me, this is a huge project and it would take years by yourself to build what you really need to make all this work.

Comment: Here is the price list. http://esd.element5.com/product.html?cart=1&productid=300487035&backlink=http%3A%2F%2Fesd.element5.com%2Fproduct.html%3Fproductid%3D300487035&cookies=1&showcart=1

Comment: You can try the software for free though by requesting a PLE key to use the watermarked version. There are lots of great tutorials to show you how to use it. Try it out.

Comment: The application is supposed to load a lot of data from a backend database... data of elections of the past. Is there a way to integrate data from a database?

Comment: Yep, there are a billion ways import data including directly through a database, RSS, XML, OSC, MIDI, and many many more. This is all very normal in Ventuz. Usually, I write backend apps to provide data and then send them in via OSC, but that's just my practice because it's the most integrated, but many people use the database nodes within the application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27446/discussion-between-marci-man-and-corylulu)

Comment: Ventuz is a brilliant Software, I have not used it for a while now but enjoy using it.